# What's the equivalent of Python's Celery project for Java?

Tags: java, python, celery, batch-processing, spring-batch

I am trying to find an equivalent of Celery project for Java environment, I have looked at Spring Batch, but are there any better alternatives for distributed task queues.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577012/whats-the-equivalent-of-pythons-celery-project-for-java (but this dupe has better answers by now...)

Answer (score 42):

What Celery is doing is very much akin to [EIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Integration_Patterns), and [SEDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staged_event-driven_architecture) with convenient task scheduling... (all you have left to do is add some DB, and async HTTP networking and you have got a complete enterprise quality stack).

Basically in Java there is the Spring way, the Java EE way, and the Hadoop way:

- **Spring:** Spring Integration + Spring Batch + RabbitMQ
- **Java EE:** Mule + Quartz or EJB Scheduling + HornetMQ
- **Hadoop:** [Capacity](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html) + ZooKeeper

Those are roughly in order of ease of setting up.

Answer (score 12):

Jesque (https://github.com/gresrun/jesque) is a Java distributed task queue library. It is a Java port of the Resque library (https://github.com/defunkt/resque), which is described like this on its GitHub page:

> Resque (pronounced like "rescue") is a Redis-backed library for creating background jobs, placing those jobs on multiple queues, and processing them later."

Answer (score 5):

Quartz has worked for me in the past.  It's integrated with Terracotta now, so it should be easy to distribute.  http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: Is it possible to do on-demand job execution with Quartz scheduler, rather than executing a job on a specific schedule?

Comment: @ZakiullahKhanMohamed I'm _very_ late but yes, this is possible. You can schedule a job to be run immediately.

Comment: Just a heads up: the open source 'free' version does not have any support for distribution.  Terracotta claims the enterprise version does.

Comment: @AdamMarcionek not sure what you mean by that. all i see is apache license and i thought that means you're basically free to distribute your software even if you're using quartz

Comment: ive only taken a short look at Quartz but the user seems to have to do a lot of the manual work to setup monitoring the system

Comment: it's important to mention that quartz is also not a job queue system.

Comment: @dtc Not distribution of code, but distribution of tasks, which is locked behind the enterprise version. And yes, as you say, its not the same as the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Celery is primarily based on Erlang/RabbitMQ. RabbitMQ has a [Java client library](http://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html) that might be useful. Also, there is [octobot](https://github.com/cscotta/Octobot) which has a RabbitMQ backend.

Comment: If I am not wrong Celery is largely written in Python and not Erlang, I would agree on the note that RabbitMQ is erlang based. Looking at octobot, thanks.

Comment: I think he means that RabbitMQ is written in Erlang, so you need to install that to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Distributed Java tasks scheduling and execution https://redisson.org/

Answer (score 3):

I found [JobRunr](https://www.jobrunr.io/en/) in Java world is pretty similar to Celery in Python world. It is a library for background processing in Java, distributed in nature and backed by persistent storage.

From their docs,

> Incredibly easy way to perform fire-and-forget, delayed, scheduled and
> recurring jobs inside Java applications using only Java 8 lambda's.
> CPU and I/O intensive, long-running and short-running jobs are
> supported. Persistent storage is done via either RDBMS (e.g. Postgres,
> MariaDB/MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, DB2 and SQLite) or NoSQL
> (ElasticSearch, MongoDB and Redis).

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I've found is Octobot: https://github.com/cscotta/Octobot
Not so much documentation though... there used to be a website for it at octobot.taco.cat, but I haven't seen that load lately.  I haven't personally used Octobot, but I've often seen it recommended as a Celery for Java.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find anything as easy to use as Celery for Java. Most of the solutions recommended to use a message queue. But Celery sits one level of abstraction higher than the queue. Instead of messages and consumers, you can think in terms of tasks and workers, results, retries etc.

I also needed to implement some bridge for a company using both Java and Python so I started this project:

**[celery-java](https://github.com/crabhi/celery-java)** - Celery client and worker in Java, compatible with their Python counterparts.

Beware, it's very immature as of now.

Answer (score -6):

Apache ActiveMQ http://activemq.apache.org/

Apache Kafka http://kafka.apache.org/

Comment: I dont think ActiveMQ and Kafta are Worker/Task Queue like celery. They are Message brokers and can be compared with RabbitMQ if you mean that.