# What is the equivalent of Celery for Clojure?

Tags: clojure, celery

If I wanted to port a Python + Celery web application to a Clojure tech stack, what options do I have for task queuing and scheduling? Can I just interop with a Java library like Quartz?

After some searching, I found [Quartzite](http://clojurequartz.info/), but have no idea about its efficacy.

Related: [What's the equivalent of Python's Celery project for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577012/whats-the-equivalent-of-pythons-celery-project-for-java)

Comment: I was faced with this too, so I'm working on a library myself, but it's still under active development and not ready yet https://github.com/d11wtq/cuckoo

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Java interop with Quartz is reasonable and should probably be your default option. I think people are sometimes too hesitant to use Java interop from Clojure, but actually it works quite well.

For evaluating Quartzite, I would take a look at the specific scheduling features you know you'll need and see if Quartzite provides interfaces to those.

Another solution developed by a coworker of mine is a native Clojure library: [Monotony](https://github.com/aredington/monotony), it might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Immutant](http://immutant.org/). It's an application server and gives you clustering, messaging, Jobs & Caching and is of high quality since it's build on top of JBOSS application server.